# Let A,B, C be fad. Consider the equation X = AX + BX + C. Must a solution X be fad?

Tags: finite-automata, formal-languages, fad

Let A,B, C be fad. Consider the equation X =  AX + BX + C. Must a solution X be fad?

Could you help me solve this question?
fad is a regular language

Comment: Quick question, what is fad?

Comment: Fad is finite automata definable or regular language

Comment: Is the `+` operator indicating a union or a concatenation? I'm assuming union. It looks like X is definable as `(A|B)*C`.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, mostly because you have not explained what you mean by your notations.

Answer (score 1):

Assume juxtaposition (AX) means concatenation, and + means union. Then, let A = B = {e} and C = {}, the FAD language containing only the empty string and the empty language, respectively. Then let X be any non-FAD language. Clearly, the equation X = AX + BX + C is true since AX = X, BX = X, and X + X + {} = X.

Here are FAs for {e} and {} (proof, if desired, is left as an exercise):

```
              /-\
--->[q0]-s->q1   | s
              \-/
      /-\
--->q0   | s
      \-/
```

If juxtaposition and union mean something else, the answer may change. For instance, it's possibly that + means concatenation, but then I don't know what to make of juxtaposition (union? intersection?).